JWTAuth queries child class db table instead of inherited User class table
I am trying to make login functionality using JWT in Laravel 10. The issue I have is that I have base User class and Artist and Client as inherited classes. The query done by JWTAuth queries the artists table looking for property 'username', but that property is in User class. This is my code in the controller.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\impl\UserRepositoryImpl;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
protected $jwt;
protected $userRepo;

public function __construct(JWTAuth $jwt, UserRepositoryImpl $userRepo)
{
    $this->jwt = $jwt;
    $this->userRepo = $userRepo;
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
    }

    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    if (!$token = $this->jwt->attempt($credentials)) {
        Log::error('Authentication failed for credentials: ', $credentials);
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
    }

    $user = $this->userRepo->findByUsername($credentials['username']);

    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User not found'], 404);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'token' => $token,
        'role' => $user->role,
    ], 200);
}

and with a bit of debugging I think the code $this->jwt->attempt($credentials) is making the issue, I am just not sure why.
Edit:
By following Raju's input I am still getting the same error:
[2024-09-01 11:46:45] local.DEBUG: Attempting to authenticate with                     
credentials:  {"username":"newclient","password":"stefan123"} 
[2024-09-01 11:46:45] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined 
column: 7 ERROR:  column "username" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "artists" where "username" = $1 limit 1
                                  ^ (Connection: pgsql, SQL: 
select * from "artists" where "username" = newclient limit 1) 

